# Django How to create a custom user from admin?

Tags: python, django

So I have this method:

```
def create_editor(self, email, dob, password):
    user = self.create_user(
        email,
        dob,
        accepted_tos=True,
        password=password
    )

    try:
        editors = Group.objects.get(name__iexact="Editors")
    except Group.DoesNotExist:
        editors = Group.objects.create(name="Editors")

    editors.permissions.add(Permission.objects.get(codename="can_give_discount")) # add can_give_discount permission
    user.groups.add(editors)
    user.save()
    return user
```

To create a normal user and then add the user to the `editor` group

I want to be able to create a manager from the normal django admin.

So in the image below I want another button called `Add Manager`

[image: django admin add user]

Comment: Please be the more specific.

Comment: Please see again the updates

Comment: Looking at the answers, we basically just guessed what you want. Maybe you still need to explain more precisely what you want to do :P

Answer (score 0):

At first it looks like what you want to do is create a new `Manager` model that has a foreignkey to user. Then from the admin side you have the option to first click add user, then navigate to the Manager model and add a manager (where you also supply the user id so they are linked by foreignkey).

However if this is only done to accommodate permissions and groups you can also go to the `groups` model in django admin.

Answer (score 0):

Spoiler alert, the django admin is not really made for customizations. But there are some think which django is prepared for, checkout the django admin docs here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#custom-template-options.

It might be a solution for you to extend/override your existing create user template (see here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-vs-replacing-an-admin-template) to e.g. add ad flag that makes the new user an editor or not and you could override the `User.objects.create()` method to use the flag.

The solution with the least amount of work but 2 steps would be to add an admin action (if you want the button in the detail view: django object action https://github.com/crccheck/django-object-actions) to "upgrade" a normal user to an editor.

Comment: Would the overriding of the existing create user template work? Where would I do the conversion of that flag into the `Group` to be added to the user?

Comment: If you really need to overwrite the admin form you basically need to recreate the django admins default 'create a new user' process. From there you need to figure out something that works for you, I would guess the flag is needed in a custom create method. I actually recommend the "upgrade" process if you never worked on customizing the admin, because it's not trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe you could add another choice field extending the User to say whether the added guy is 'Editor' or 'Manager' and on save check if the added user is 'Manager' or 'Editor', and override save to add the new user to the corresponding group.